# How do I plot a 2D numpy array where every column is a different function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I've done some googlig on plotting 2D numpy arrays and it seems people only interpret these as bitmaps.

In my case, however, the row number is an X coordinate and every cell contains a Y coordinate, every column representing a different y=f(x) function. I would like to just plot all these lines (represented by columns) on a simple line chart.

What is the least verbose way to do this? Or do I have to extract every column and plot it manually one by one?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Did you try `pylab.plot(yourarray)`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer it says "No protocol specified, qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0, Could not connect to any X display." All the other Qt apps work just fine (I use the latest KDE).

Comment: Looks like something with your matplotlib installation is not right. I think it would be acceptable for you to make a new question about that if you can't fix it yourself.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Now I've restarted my PC and the error is gone. I didn't restart it for more than a week, the X server has seemingly got tired :-) It seems `pylab.plot(yourarray)`  is exactly what I was looking for. You can submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.pylab.plot` when given a 2D input will plot each column as a separate line. Therefore all you need to do is

```
pylab.plot(yourarray)
```

This will seemingly do nothing. To get a tangible result you need to do at least one of the following:

```
pylab.show()
```

and/or

```
pylab.savefig('yourfilename.png')
```

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that one has to call `pylab.show()` after `pylab.plot(yourarray)` to actually get the plot displayed as this may be not obvious for the newcomers.